# WEMOS: How to install it?

Tags: nodemcu

I have been using an Arduino Uno for a year now, and I bought a WEMOS D1 Mini and a NodeMCU. I want to select WEMOS or NodeMCU from the Arduino Web Editor but it doesn't appear on the list:

[image: Arduino Editor Board List]

I think I need to install a driver but it's only for the Arduino desktop editor (not for the web editor).

Comment: I don't believe you can. Only Arduino can do that sort of thing, since it's their web server.

Comment: You have to go to the website and download the driver. Also make sure you add the ESP8266 stable to ur preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read that it can't. It's a shame:

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=441328.0